# Is it good practice to run a loop in a Worker class constructor that I initialise in another Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, class, python-multithreading

I have a Worker class that is called by a GUI button. This class has a long-running loop in its constructor. This loop monitors the the process when it is working (`self.process_a_is_alive==True`) or waits for the GUI to send instructions when the process is not working (`self.process_a_is_alive==False`).

Since I'm not very experienced in working with Threads, I'm unsure if its good practice to run this loop in the constructor itself.

In the below example, I have excluded the GUI and directly called it from a `if __name__ == __main__` block

```
from threading import Thread

class WorkerA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # doSomething()
        
        # Lots of code here
        
        # initialise the ProcessA instance
        
        self.worker_mainloop()
    
    # is_alive property is defined here
    # process_is_alive property is defined here
    
    def worker_mainloop
        
class ProcessA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # doSomething2()
        
        # Process code here, 
        
        self._process_loop()
    # is_alive property is defined here
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Thread(target=WorkerA, args=())
    w.start()
    
    while w.is_alive():
        # doSomething3()
```

While this is working, I've looked at examples of threading, and have not seen what I have done here. So I'm somewhat paranoid that what I'm doing is bad practice.

Comment: Generally speaking, `__init__` should only *prepare* an object for its intended use.